# A number $a$ is a primitive root mod $n$ if and only if $\{a, a^2 , . . . , a^{\varphi(n)}\}$ is a complete set of residues prime to n.

Tags: number-theory

A number $a$ is a primitive root $\bmod n$ if and only if $\{a, a^2 , . . . , a^{\varphi(n)}\}$ is a complete set of residues prime to $n$. Is this true or false?

Comment: How are you defining "primitive root" in this context?

Comment: a is a primitive root mod n if gcd(a,n) =1 and order of a mod n is φ(n)

Comment: This is not a problem in group theory. I suggest you revise the definition of group theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True if you define 'a' is primitive root iff order of 'a'
is $\phi (n)$.

If this were not true, then for some $i,j \leq \phi (n):$

You would have: $a^i = a^j \implies a^{i-j}=1$ where $i-j < \phi(n)$

This is a contradiction because a is a primitive root and the order is $\phi(n)$ not less than it.

*Are you in mat315 at UofT?*